# Get the friendly url of a page with php

Tags: php, web, request, friendly-url, breadcrumbs

I have the next problem:

I'm trying to get the friendly url of a web page for creating breadcrumps. This web page has a weird way to creat the friendly urls so I cant use my common system

```
$dirlist = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
$count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

then I make a loop

```
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $url=$address .= '/'.$dirlist[$i];
}
```

And the code explains itself I guess, I print an UL and stuff...

Well the page that is giving me problems doesn't work with this so I think if I could get just the URL I could work with that.

For example the url on the browser looks like `"www.potato.com/en/vegetables/blog"`

So I'm trying to get with PHP this, but I can't. I can't do it with `REQUEST_URI` or `REQUEST_URL`...

Thanks!